# How to style a React Component in the HTML

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm mapping through an array and I want to set the background color based on if that element is stored in the user Profile but I'm having trouble setting the background color and I'm getting this error.  *'Invariant Violation: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX. This DOM node was rendered by `AddingHabit`'*

```
      <div>{this.renderHabits().map((habitObject)=>{
              return (<div className="addingHabitPic habitpics" key={habitObject.imageLink} id="picplusdiv"> <img src={habitObject.imageLink} height="288" width="197"/> <div style="background-color:black" className="testdiv">Where is text?</div></div>)
           })}
      </div>
```

Black will be substituted with a variable later but this is just to get it working.  I've tried style={{background-color:black}} as the error suggests but no luck.  This is using React with Meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it except that you have to use a slightly different syntax when doing this mapping. Instead of dash deliniated styles, you have to use camelCase (also, you wrote down `black` but that's a variable which isn't defined so instead you need a string `'black'`). The following would work:

```
{{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}
```

You can apply the same logic to almost all other css styles.

Comment: Thanks dude you rock.  I'll mark you as the correct answer in 8 minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

[Read the docs!](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)

This  situation is covered in the React docs. You cannot pass a string to the `styles` prop - you *must* pass in an object:

```
var divStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
};
```

and do `<div style = {divStyle}>` in your render call.